# PamGuard Click Train Detector is not colouring detected click trains

Tags: pamguard, echolocation-clicks

I have just started to do some tests in the PamGuard Click Train Detector.
I ran some data from Riso’s dolphin that has a lot of click trains.
For starting, I kept the default configuration for dolphins  in:  Settings>  Click Train Detector >  Detection Settings > Optimise for Species > Dolphin
After running it , by right clicking in ‘Settings’ In the click detector display,  I chose  ‘Colour by Click Train (Click Trains)’.
As far as I have seen in tutorials each click train detected should be coloured with a different colour. But instead, I have got all click trains detected coloured in grey. Not sure why it did not show different colours as I suppose it should  and I don't know if the algorithm is working  properly in this case.
I am using the latest PG version (2.02.09 Core), here is a print of how the click detector display looks like:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is your array settings and does it correspond to reality? I suspect that the TDOA estimation is not working, so clicktrains are not allocated

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I double checked the array configuration and it's correct. This array has a pair of high frequency hydrophones 1.01m apart. The bearings seem to make sense, typical from dolphins moving fast.  

It seems to me that click trains are allocated but instead of displaying different colours for each click train they are all coloured in grey.  When I enable the box for `Event click only`  the display shows only those grey colour clicks trains. I just added a new image to illustrate it.

Comment: Do the gray colored detections turn back to black if you turn off 'Color by click train'? If so then it seems like it is working partway, but just not the colors you want. You may need to go into the settings option of the right-clicked menu and see if you can color 'randomly' or something similar to that. That is an option for whistles and moans but I'm not as familiar with click trains

Comment: Thanks for the comment Selene.  I have tried looking for more settings after your suggestion.  I could not find settings for colouring like the whistle and moan detector, but I finally found the settings to do it.  It is quite easy and simple.  In the Click Train Detector settings window go to  ‘Detector Selector’  and enable  ‘Automatically detected  clicks trains’ and that will do. The click trains are now coloured,  and I can see the individual clicks trains detected by the algorithm.  I attached the figure in case this might be helpful to anyone.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Great news! If you have a second, it would be great if you convert this comment into and Answer (you can answer your own question and accept it) which will allow others to find the fix more easily.

Comment: I have done it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone has this issue when using the click train detector in PamGuard, it is quite easy and simple to troubleshoot it. In the Click Train Detector settings window go to ‘Detector Selector’ and enable ‘Automatically detected clicks trains’ and that will do. The click trains will be coloured (different colours for each click train), and you will be able to see the individual click trains detected by the algorithm. I attached the figure in case this might be helpful to anyone.